# SpringBoot health Endpoints overriden

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am trying to write an extension for the acutator health endpoint.
Following the documentation  as per https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Migrating-a-custom-Actuator-endpoint-to-Spring-Boot-2

However I don't see the my extension being invoked.
I do see this message Overriding bean definition for bean 'healthEndpointWebExtension' with a different definition:
So the extension I created is being overriden with the default version provided by Spring

Comment: were you able to resolve this?  I'm having a similar issue trying to extend the env endpoint.

Comment: Standard actuator endpoints are not really meant to be overridden and this page meant to explain how to do this for your own endpoint, not the one Spring Boot ships by default.

Answer (score 4):

Use this code and keep in mind that name of your class **MUST** be exactly HealthEndpointWebExtension

```
@Component
@EndpointWebExtension(endpoint = HealthEndpoint.class)
public class HealthEndpointWebExtension {

@Autowired
private HealthEndpoint delegate;

@ReadOperation
public WebEndpointResponse<Health> getHealth() {
    Health health = this.delegate.health();
    Integer status = getStatus(health);
    return new WebEndpointResponse<>(health, status);
}
}
```

Comment: still doesn't work. this is pretty much what i did. no exceptions also for me to debug

Comment: This doesn't work and gives me a duplicate bean definition exception: `A bean with that name has already been defined`

Answer (score 4):

Just tested with 2.1.1.RELEASE: Provide your own `@WebEndpoint` like

```
@Component
@WebEndpoint(id = "acmehealth")
public class AcmeHealthEndpoint {

    @ReadOperation
    public String hello() {
      return "hello health";
    }
}
```

and

1. include it
2. map the original /health to, say, /internal/health
3. map your custom endpoint to /health

via `application.properties`:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=acmehealth
management.endpoints.web.path-mapping.health=internal/health
management.endpoints.web.path-mapping.acmehealth=/health
```

The important part here is to map the original endpoint to somewhere else. In doing so you prevent the collision.

Comment: That's the way to override the default implementation easily. The real endpoint can be injected and used as a delegate in the custom one.

Answer (score 2):

Akkave is correct. However,as a supplementary, you need to set the package same with spring one: `package org.springframework.boot.actuate.health;` to ensure it overide the spring's bean!

Answer (score 2):

You can not actually write EndpointWebExtension for predefine acutator URL. But what you can do is you can overwrite the existing definition for EndpointWebExtension like below. You can write custom logic as per requirement.

```
@Component

@EndpointWebExtension(endpoint = HealthEndpoint.class)

public class CustomeEndpointWebExtension extends HealthEndpointWebExtension {

    private static final String[] NO_PATH = {};
    public HealthWebEndpointWebExtension(HealthContributorRegistry registry, HealthEndpointGroups groups) {
        super(registry, groups);

    }

//To write custom logic for /acuator/health
    @ReadOperation
    public WebEndpointResponse<HealthComponent> health(ApiVersion apiVersion, SecurityContext securityContext) {
        System.out.println("#@Start");
        WebEndpointResponse<HealthComponent> health = health(apiVersion, securityContext, false, NO_PATH);
        //Can write customer logic here as per requirment
        System.out.println("#@End"+health.getBody().getStatus());
        return health;
    }

//To write custom logic for /acuator/health/db
    @ReadOperation
    public WebEndpointResponse<HealthComponent> health(ApiVersion apiVersion, SecurityContext securityContext,
            @Selector(match = Match.ALL_REMAINING) String... path) {
        WebEndpointResponse<HealthComponent> health = health(apiVersion, securityContext, false, path);
        System.out.println("#Status"+health.getBody().getStatus());
        return health;
    }

}
```

Comment: Should the above run when I view `[myhost:port]/actuator/health` from a browser?  It doesn't for me